# TableLayoutPanel wont show up in new form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, tablelayoutpanel

I have a working Form1 and I am opening a new Form2. I want a table of results in my Form2 when I open it, however the table is not showing up no matter what I do. I used some code from another question I found, and still no luck.

This is my call from Form1 (The window opens fine, it's just empty)

```
Form2 Display = new Form2(List<objects>);
Display.Show();
```

Here is the code in my Form2

```
namespace DBTest
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(List<Audit_Record> ResultsList)
        {
            TableLayoutPanel Results = new TableLayoutPanel();
            Results.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
            Results.ColumnCount = 5;
            Results.RowCount = 1;
            Results.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 150F));
            Results.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            Results.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 150F));
            Results.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 150F));
            Results.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 100F));
            Results.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 50F));
            Results.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Audit ID" }, 1, 0);
            Results.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Field Changes" }, 2, 0);
            Results.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Date" }, 3, 0);
            Results.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Employee ID" }, 4, 0);
            Results.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Action" }, 5, 0);

            Results.RowCount = Results.RowCount + 1;
            Results.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = ResultsList[0].auditID }, 1, 1);
            Results.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = "Old: " + ResultsList[0].fieldChanges[0].fieldName + " New: " + ResultsList[0].fieldChanges[0].fieldNewValue + " Old: " + ResultsList[0].fieldChanges[0].fieldOldValue }, 2, 1);
            Results.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = ResultsList[0].timeOfAudit.ToString() }, 3, 1);
            Results.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = ResultsList[0].employeeID }, 4, 1);
            Results.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = ResultsList[0].action }, 5, 1);

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Not even the titles are showing up. I am new to .net and visual studio.

Comment: You can't add controls before InitializeComponent().

Comment: Okay, however switching the InitializeComponent() above doesn't solve it either.

Comment: You didn't add it to the form : This.Controls.Add(Results);

Comment: Ah... that would seem to have solved it. Thanks

Comment: You should of gotten an error if you added the control before InitializeComponent();  both fixes were needed.